# Want to improve the computing speed of matrix calculation, OpenMP or CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, openmp

My program has a  bunch of matrix multiplication and inversion, which is time consuming.

My computer: CPU: intel i7;  GPU: 512MB NVIDIA® Quadro® NVS3100M

Which one is better for improving computing speed? OpenMP or CUDA?

(ps. I think generally, GPU has more cores than cpu, thus, CUDA could improve multiple times more than OpenMP?)

Comment: You should try them both and benchmark.

Comment: Yes, I will, however, I learnt a little CUDA more than 1 year ago, and have no idea of OpenMP. How long it will take me to learn OpenMP?

Comment: I'd hope you would use an optimised library tbh.

Comment: the answer is yes.  obscure?  because your question is obscure.  one isn't necessarily *better* than the other.  OpenMP is for multi-processing programming.  CUDA is for NVIDIA GPU programming.  On your specific platform for matrix operations, CUDA is probably better.  It also frees up your CPU for other stuff that you may be doing.

Comment: You can learn a couple OpenMP pragmas in no time; `parallel for`, for instance, is a really easy-to-use pragma (just make sure you're careful about which variables you declare to be `private`). I'm not sure how long it would take you to become really proficient in OpenMP.

Comment: it would depend of the quantity of elements in your matrix and how often you are trying to call this function. If is a very large number, you definitely should use cuda. Like this functions like matrix multiplication are very common used with cuda, you have libraries implementing this, just read some about thrust https://developer.nvidia.com/thrust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience(work on both as a school project, in most condition, the calculation time for a medium size array, I would say less than 2000 * 2000, is almost the same, the actual calculation time depending on the working load of your computer(usually when you working on openMP, you would share a cluster with other guys, so make sure you are running your application alone, so that you might got a better result))

But if you are good at CUDA, the GPU is very powerful in these kinds of calculation stuff, when i was working on my CUDA project, there are lots of good materials in the official website. For openMP, it is only a library, and if you are good at c or c++, should not be any problem for you to use it(but the compiler of openMP is buggy~~, don't trust it, try to log anything).

And i assumed you have experience on CUDA, is not hard to find some good example i think. But CUDA is really dummy, can't debug, so I recommend you to try openMP first, it should be easier.

Comment: Of course is it possible to debug CUDA! Nvidia also delivers powerful gui's for the cuda-gdb, which you can use in visual studio oder nsight eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it depends on what your application is and how you go about trying to implement improvements. Keep in mind that every optimization has tradeoffs. For instance, GPU's typically use half-precision floating point, and there are compiler options that allow you to bypass some aspects of the IEEE standard, which brings you some extra speed at the expense of precision, etc.

Comment: CUDA has had double precision for a very long time now. I feel this is a bit of a non-answer, it basically says "it depends" without giving sensible criteria of what it depends on.

Comment: That's true, though the criteria should probably be part of the original question; without that, there's really no way to know what the "right" technology to use is.